# How to make [Flags] enum and switch case work together?

Tags: c#, enums, switch-statement, bitflags

How to make [Flags] enum and switch case work together? Very desirable to make it looks simple. Similar Questions asked many times, but never directly to [Flags] enum.

If M1 set execute operation 1,

if M2 set execute operation2 ,

if BOTH M1 and M2 then set execute operation 1 and 2.

```
 [Flags]
    public enum TST
    {
        M1 =1,
        M2 =2,
        M3 =4
    }

 public void PseudoCode()
    {

        TST t1 = TST.M1 | TST.M3; //1+2= 3

        switch( t1)
        {
            case TST.M1:
                {
                    //Do work if Bit 1 set
                }
            case TST.M2:
                {
                    //Do work if Bit 2 set
                }
            case TST.M3:
                {
                    //Do work if Bit 3 set
                }
            default:
                {
                    //nothing set;
                    break;
                }
        }

    }
```

I also quite sure a lot of people want to know how to make it work. Request fix of C#?

Comment: You can easily do this but you have to add all the unique combinations yourself. A switch picks 1 case, it doesn't pick N matching cases, that's the purpose of a switch so you're going to have to use a different method (if-statements) or just live with how it works.

Comment: And just to be clear, this is not a bug, so this won't get "fixed". This is 100% by design and will not be changed the way you want it to behave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will execute for any bit set

for example

```
ExecuteOnFlagValue(TST.M1 | TST.M3); //1+2= 3
```

Will execute code for bits 1 and 3

```
public void ExecuteOnFlagValue(TST value) {
    if (value & TST.M1 == TST.M1) {
        //Do work if bit 1
    }
    if (value & TST.M2 == TST.M2) {
        //Do work if bit 2
    }
    if (value & TST.M3 == TST.M3) {
        //Do work if bit 3
    }
}
```

Comment: @justromagod, if you find that the response works, please mark it as accepted, so others will be confident that it works

Comment: compiler error because operator '&' can't be applied to operands of type of value on the left and boolean value on the right. ((value & TST.M1) == TST.M1) works better.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with `switch` in c#, since once a case is executed, no other case will be executed.
You can think of a `switch` statement as a shorter way to write `if... else if... else...` constructs - where each `case` is an `if`, and the `default` is the final `else`:

This means that the following `switch` statement:

```
switch( t1)
{
    case TST.M1:
        //Do work if Bit 1 set
        break;
    case TST.M2:
        //Do work if Bit 2 set
        break;
    case TST.M3:
        //Do work if Bit 3 set
        break;
    default:
        //nothing set;
        break;
}
```

Is equivalent to the following `if...else if... else` construct:

```
if(t1 == TST.M1)
{
    //Do work if only Bit 1 set
}
else if (t1 == TST.M2)
{
    //Do work if only Bit 2 set
}
else if (t1 == TST.M3)
{
    //Do work if only Bit 3 set
}
else
{
    //nothing set or multiple bits set
}
```

Comment: In case of TST.M1  | TST.M2 your code will not execute the part corresponding with bit 3, becase the else if structure. Also the comparation t1 == TSM.whatever will fai because t1 is a flag enum with 2 bits set

Comment: This does not work, the first `if`-condition is *only* true if t1 is **exactly** TST.M1, if t1 is `TST.M1 | TST.M2`, the condition will not evaluate true.

Comment: @ikkentim That is exactly my point. This is a demonstraiting why the switch can't work like the OP wants it to.

Comment: Might want to adjust your answer then, since this is not clear in your answer, all you're saying is that multiple cases won't run. Nothing about the difference between checking bits vs checking exact value

Comment: Yes, well, I was rudely interrupted before completing the edits I wanted to do on this answer... never mind, the answer by mnieto already covered the rest.